# QRegExp не работает как ожидалось

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRegExp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QRegExp rx = QRegExp("^[\w]+[\d]*$");
    qDebug() << rx.indexIn("xj");
    qDebug() << rx.indexIn("12s");
    return 0;
}
```

Ожидалось что в первом случае будет 0, но получил -1. На этом сайте http://regexr.com/ все ОК, а в Qt нет.

Comment: А экранирование не помешает? Попробуйте: `"^[\\w]+[\\d]*$"`

Comment: @gil9red помогло

Comment: Я тогда в ответ это добавлю, чтобы не висел вопрос без ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было экранировать слеши в строке: `"^[\\w]+[\\d]*$"`

```
QRegExp rx = QRegExp("^[\\w]+[\\d]*$");
```